# How to display line numbers with pygmentize

Tags: command-line, colors, source-code, cat

I often use the command `pygmentize filename.py` to show color source files with code formatting. This works like a charm. I now also want to show line numbers like `cat -n filename.py` does.

I read around and found some suggestions like adding `-O linenos=1` or `-O linenos=True`. None of this seems to work though.

Does anybody have any idea how I can show line numbers when viewing source files on the command line with [pygments](http://pygments.org/)? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add line numbers using `perl` like this:

```
pygmentize file.py | perl -e 'print ++$i." $_" for <>'
```

---

**Update** (to alias the previous command):

To create an alias, just define the following bash function somewhere in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
pyg() {
pygmentize $1 | perl -e 'print ++$i." $_" for <>'
}
```

Open a new terminal and call the command with `pyg file.py`.

Comment: Awesome, that seems to work. Just one last question: would you know how to change this in an alias so that I can do something like this `myalias thefile.py`?

Comment: @kramer65: I've added a function to copy/paste in your `.bashrc`

Comment: Awesome! I didn't expect to be ever using perl, but this works like a charm! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried piping the output to `nl --body-numbering=a`? As for most shell tools, you can find more information in `man nl`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That indeed gives some numbers. Unfortunately it doesn't count the empty lines, which causes the line numbers not to be correct with what is given in stacktraces of errors I get. Any other ideas?

Comment: It's numbering empty lines for me, be sure to include the `--body-numbering=a` argument, as that tells `nl` to number _all_ lines. `-ba` also works.

Answer (score 1):

Using cat with piping:

```
pygmentize filename.py | cat -n
```

Sylvain's answer is somehow better since it doesn't generates additional cat's trailing whitespaces at the beginning of each line. But at some point you may not have pearl installed :)

Try also:

```
pygmentize -g filename.py | cat -n | sed "s/^[ \t]*//"
```

It gives you nice space between line numbers and the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
pygmentize < hello.go | awk '{print i++ + 1 "   " $0}'
```

This works for me. Note +1 is there because you want first line to be labelled 1 not 0.

Answer (score 0):

I added some formatting tweaks to the accepted answer to suit my needs

```
ccatn() {
        pygmentize -g -O full,style=monokai $1 | perl -e 'for(<>){print sprintf("%3s %s", ++$i,$_);}'
}
```

use it like
`ccatn helloworld.go`

Answer (score 0):

For me this here worked without needing any other command:

```
pygmentize -g -O full,style=monokai,linenos=1 file.py
```

I still put the command in my ~/.bash_aliases as an "alias":

```
alias ccat='pygmentize -g -O full,style=monokay,lineos=1'
```

Now I can use it as a ccat command :-)

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to [Varun Narayanan's `awk` answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1160105/1696301), and with a `pygments` old version whose [`Terminal256Formatter`](https://pygments.org/docs/formatters/#Terminal256Formatter) doesn't support the `linenos` option:

```sh
pygmentize filename.py | awk '{printf("%5d │ %s\n",++i,$0)}'
```

This one has a better line number padding and uses the same lineno/code separator as the [`bat`](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat) formatter ([*Box Drawings Light Vertical* = `│` = `\u2502` = `&boxv;`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2502)).